# Adding some fields to return value of parent

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, inheritance, django-models

I have an abstract class in my Django models which have some children. I have a method in my parent model like follows :

```
def get_info(self):
    return {
        'name': self.name,
        'username': self.username,
        'about': self.about,
    }
```

I want in my child classes to add some extra fields into this dictionary. How can I get parent output add some fields and return result.( In child method has the same name `get_info`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inherit the function in child class, call the super class function and then update the dictionary returned by the parent class

```
class A:
    def get_info(self):
        return {
            'name': self.name,
            'username': self.username,
            'about': self.about

        }

class B(A):
    def get_info(self):
        data = super(B, self).get_info()
        data.update({
            'b_attribute': self.something
        })
        return data
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `super().get_info` to access the method of the parent class, it will find the parent class according to the Method Resolution Order (MRO).
or specify which parent you want to call the method from if you have multiple parent.
`super(SpecifyParent, self).get_info`